# How to create an HTTP get request from a sharepoint online site, to another sites api

Tags: sharepoint, get, python-requests

Is it possible to create an HTTP get the request that is sent from SharePoint online and retrieve the data and save it to the SharePoint site in documents?

I do this locally now, and it looks like you can do it with the SharePoint server on an on-premises installation. but I'm not sure about SharePoint online.

Is it possible to run the script as a service on SharePoint online, the way I do locally?

I know I can do something like this with azure so that the whole installation is cloud-based, but I would like to do it on SharePoint online, just for simplicity's sake without the added maintenance, plus we aren't doing anything other than basic file retrieval.

also, any information about scripting in SharePoint online would be helpful. from the documentation I've seen, I can't tell that SharePoint online has this capability.

any help would be great.

Comment: Correct words and grammar

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run server-side services such as timer jobs on SharePoint Online. All custom logic will "move down" to the client computer, or "move up" to a local server outside the SharePoint farm or SharePoint Online subscription.

Keeping custom code off SharePoint online could prevent the custom code from harming their servers or reduce the performance of their SharePoint Online websites.

BR

Comment: That was my impression, thank you for the clarification.